# return list with integers and string from list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, integer

```
['10019', 'Airma25KLOS', 'Juridinis', 'LT', '121979631', 'LT219796314', '2410', '25', '26', '3232', '32131']
```

In this list every item is a string, how could I make from this list, same list with same order but instead of integers that are strings now like 10019'  '121979631' and so on, be returned as ints.

My goal is to make list look like this

```
[10019, 'Airma25KLOS', 'Juridinis', 'LT', 121979631, 'LZ219796314', 2410, 25, 26, 3232, 32131]
```

and if there is a mix of letters and numbers it should stay as a string like LZ219796314'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This one should work for any string that is a valid representation of an integer (wether positive or negative). Not that if won't work with floats though.

```
def to_int(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except (TypeError, ValueError) as e:
        return s

result = [to_int(s) for s in your_list]
```

Comment: Yep, this is what I was thinking along the lines of. +1

Answer (score 7):

You could use the following list comprehension with [`.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) in order to convert to `int` only numeric strings:

```
l = ['10019', 'Airma25KLOS', 'Juridinis', 'LT', '121979631', 
     'LT219796314', '2410', '25', '26', '3232', '32131']

[int(i) if i.lstrip('-').isdigit() else i for i in l]
# [10019, 'Airma25KLOS', 'Juridinis', 'LT', 121979631, 'LT219796314', 
#  2410, 25, 26, 3232, 32131]
```

Comment: Not quite robust. What if one of the integers is negative?

Comment: @JohnColeman is right. In my view, a more rigorous method would be to define a separate function to do a more robust check on whether or not a string is an integer.

Comment: @JohnColeman good point. Will add an update contemplating negative ints also

Comment: @yatu It depends on the intended application. For positive integer base-10 literals (which OP seems to have in mind), this is fine. OP should certainly know about `isdigit()`, but should also know its limitations.

Comment: Added a `.lstrip('-')` to also handle negative digits

Comment: And if you have a positive integer `'+1'` or a decimal number `'1.0'`?

Comment: This approach only works for integers, as well as the other proposed solution. For a + sign you can simply left strip both by - and +,  `i.lstrip('+-')` @MykolaZotko

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex to check if a string is an integer:

```
import re

p = re.compile(r'[+-]?\d+')

[int(i) if p.fullmatch(i) else i for i in l]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this out:

```
l=['-10019', 'Airma25KLOS', 'Juridinis', 'LT', '121979631', 'LT219796314', '2410', '25', '26', '3232', '32131']
a=[]
for item in l:
    try:
        a.append(int(item))
    except:
        a.append(item)
```

I am not sure if this is the best method to this, but this works for all integers (positive and negative)